# What tools do I need to replace this rusted p trap

Tags: sink, p-trap

This sink is draining very slowly but this p trap seems rusted.

What tools and part would I need to remove this? Tried pliers and nothing seems to budge. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some adjustable pliers, Channellocks or a pipe wrench to turn those nuts on the trap. Spray some CLR or WD-40 on both of them to loosen up the grime. You'll need a new trap and probably a new drain pipe extension coming out of the wall because of the corrosion. It looks like the drain pipe extension comes off by loosening the large nut. Use some CLR or WD-40 there too. The down pipe from the sink looks OK since it appears to be copper.